# Gmail API & Woocommerce transactional email: 130emails/day? how to increase users in admin & sending limits?

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, gmail-api

I choose GSuite to send out SMTP transactional emails for a woocommerce shop. 
I'm using the plugin WP mail SMTP... Everything is woking great and emails do not end up in SPAM folders (I used mailgun before and in fact yahoo and outlook emails did just that... that's the reason I'm using Gsuite now)

1) As I understand GSuite delivers 130 transactional mails/day? The sending limit is 130/day. That's correct? Because in my api dashboard the number 200 shows up.

2) How can I track, how much emails are send/day? I use the API dashboard or which site inside google api do I use for that?

3) Can I increase the transactional emails/day? I've read somewhere that it is possible to add a user for free in my admin so my sending limits increase to 2*130/day... I cannot find the article. Is this accurate and how do I add a user for free?

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota),

**1) As I understand GSuite delivers 130 transactional mails/day? The sending limit is 130/day. That's correct? Because in my api dashboard the number 200 shows up.**

> Gmail API is subject to a daily usage limit that applies to all
>   requests made from your application, as well as per-user rate limits.
>   The following table details the main request limits:
>
> [image: Gmail Quota][1]]

**2) How can I track, how much emails are send/day? I use the API dashboard or which site inside google api do I use for that?**

> To view or change usage limits for your project, or to request an
>   increase to your quota, do the following:
>
> 1. If you don't already have a [billing account](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6288653) for your
>      project, then create one.
> 2. [Visit the Enabled APIs page of the API library](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/enabled) in the
>      API Console, and select an API from the list.
> 3. To view and change quota-related settings, select **Quotas**. To view usage statistics, select **Usage**.

**3) Can I increase the transactional emails/day? I've read somewhere that it is possible to add a user for free in my admin so my sending limits increase to 2*130/day... I cannot find the article. Is this accurate and how do I add a user for free?**

> Mail Sending Limits
>
> The Gmail API enforces the standard daily [mail sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852) (these
>   limits differ for paying G Suite users vs free gmail.com users).
>
> These limits are per-user and are shared by all of the user's clients,
>   whether API clients, native/web clients or SMTP MSA. If these limits
>   are exceeded a HTTP 429 Too Many Requests "User-rate limit exceeded"
>   error mentioning "(Mail sending)" is returned with a time to retry.
>   Note that daily limits being exceeded may result in these types of
>   errors for multiple hours before the request is accepted, so your
>   client may retry the request with standard exponential backoff.
>
> These per-user limits cannot be increased for any reason.
>
> The mail sending pipeline is complex: once the user exceeds their
>   quota, there can be a delay of several minutes before the API begins
>   to return 429 error responses. So you cannot assume that a 200
>   response means the email was successfully sent.